# Converting array of json objects to 2-D array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json

I have array of JSON objects as follows:

```
var out = [{
  1: {
    name: 'Name 1',
    id: 'one'

  }
}, {
  2: {
    name: 'Name 2',
    id: 'two'
  }
}];
```

I am trying to convert this to 2-D array as:

```
var out = [[1,object],[2,object]];
```

I tried to use json.encode(out) , any methods or approaches for converting this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

simply try

```
var output  = out.map(function(val){
  var keyName = parseInt(Object.keys(val)[0],10);
  var value =  val[keyName];
  return [keyName, value];
});
```

**DEMO**

```js
var out = [{
  1: {
    name: 'Name 1',
    id: 'one'
  }
}, {
  2: {
    name: 'Name 2',
    id: 'two'
  }
}];

var output = out.map(function(val) {
  var keyName = parseInt(Object.keys(val)[0],10);
  var value = val[keyName];
  return [keyName, value];
});

document.body.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(output,0,4);
```

Comment: you have forgot that "1" and "2" should be numbers

Answer (score 3):

You can use **[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** and **[`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)**

```js
var out = [{
  1: {
    name: 'Name 1',
    id: 'one'

  }
}, {
  2: {
    name: 'Name 2',
    id: 'two'
  }
}];

var res = out.map(function(v) {
  var key = Object.keys(v)[0];
  return [parseInt(key,10), v[key]];
})

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(res, null, 3) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: you have forgot that "1" and "2" should be numbers

Answer (score 3):

A proposal for a more dynamic data structure, without stress to the first key

```js
var out = [{ 1: { name: 'Name 1', id: 'one' } }, { 2: { name: 'Name 2', id: 'two' } }],
    result = [];

out.forEach(function (a) {
    Object.keys(a).forEach(function (k) {
        result.push([+k, a[k]]);
    });
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: you have forgot that "1" and "2" should be numbers

Answer (score 1):

To meet your requirement: (`[[1,object],[2,object]]`) *`"1"` and `"2"` keys should be numbers*:

```
var result = out.map(function(v){
    var k = Object.keys(v)[0];
    return [parseInt(k),v[k]];
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(result,0,4));
```

The *console.log* output:

```
[
    [
        1,
        {
            "name": "Name 1",
            "id": "one"
        }
    ],
    [
        2,
        {
            "name": "Name 2",
            "id": "two"
        }
    ]
]
```